# Java color with RGB?

Tags: java

How can I get RGB colors in Java in a class?

I need make the Animal Kingdom and that is the first problem I have.

```
    package model.general;

public class Animal {

    protected String name;
    protected Double weight;
    protected String bodyCovering;


}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't have any mention of color anywhere - what do you need color for? You can use the Java implemention of [Color](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) if you just need a storage object for RGB values.

Comment: It's the first Java project I do, so I've no idea.

Comment: And I need use different colors for different animals.

Comment: @Korkel : A step-by-step basics tutorial website, such as w3schools and codeacademy should be your first stop. SO discourages unclear and basic questions that do not demonstrate minimal learning effort by askers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Color** in your class.

```
protected Color color;
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do what you want:

```
package model.general;

import java.awt.Color;

public class Animal {

    protected String name;
    protected Double weight;
    protected String bodyCovering;

    protected Color color;
}
```